# Octave execution annoying behavior

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-16.04, octave

I have installed Octave following the steps from this article:

https://medium.com/@manivannan_data/install-octave-on-ubuntu-16-04-d76f97e0d504

The version is 4.2.2, my OS is Linux Mint Sylvia 18.3.

The problem is that when I execute /usr/bin/octave from terminal, it opens the GUI as intended but the terminal keeps opened and I find that annoying, if I close the terminal, the GUI closes as well. I switched from Matlab for the very same behavior and don't know what to do. I tried to daemonized it but didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what behaviour you want. Are you trying to start Octave GUI without the terminal window? Or just starting Octave on the command line without the GUI?

Comment: When you open any program from the terminal, the terminal is the parent process. Killing it will kill the other program too. This is not Octave behavior, it is how Unices work. Please describe the desired behavior, there might be a workaround.

Comment: I want to be able to run Octave GUI without any terminal window opened.
For example, when I do _/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text_ it opens up Sublime Text, but then I can close the terminal windows and Sublime Text GUI would still be opened

Comment: This isn't something special to GNU Octave. If you start the GUI from a terminal in the background then you have to call `disown` before closing the terminal

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't quite understand Ubuntu very well yet, but after searching the web, I came upon with the answers for both applications.

For the case of Octave:

Create a launcher with the option --force-gui and indicating Terminal=false, e.g.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Octave
Type=Application
Icon=<Path/To/Icon>
Exec=/usr/bin/octave --force-gui
Terminal=false
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/616827/how-to-force-octave-to-launch-in-gui-mode-from-the-dock

And for the case of Matlab:

Create a launcher with the option -desktop and indicating Terminal=false, e.g.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Matlab
Type=Application
Icon=<Path/To/Icon>
Exec=/usr/local/MATLAB/<Matlab Version>/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB -desktop 
Terminal=false
```

Reference: https://la.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/20-how-do-i-make-a-desktop-launcher-for-matlab-in-linux

In both cases just by clicking the launcher, it will open the GUI without the terminal.
If anyone has encountered the same problems, hope this answer helps.